# Product of integers until input is zero in java

Tags: java, while-loop

Hey guys I am absolutely new to coding in java. I have tried to make a program that takes the input of the user and multiplies these inputs together until the user inputs zero. The program should then stop and output the product of all previous numbers. The problem is that when I enter "0" after a sequence of numbers, it uses that zero in the sequence of products. After entering zero for the second time it finally stops but then the total product equals zero.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Product{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
    int number; 
    int prod; 

     void doProd(){
         prod = 1;

         while (sc.nextInt() != 0) {
             number = sc.nextInt();
             prod = prod * number;
         }
         System.out.println( "Product is "+ prod );
     }   

     public static void main( String[] a ) {
      (new Product()).doProd();
     }
 }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: you're using two calls to `nextInt()` on each loop iteration. The first value entered by the user is effectively ignored if it's not 0... and if the user enters 0 for the second value, it's not going to stop the loop.

Comment: thanks! i have changed the nextInt() in the while loop to "number". So that my input number should not be 0. Also i have given number an initial value of 1 as well. But now my product seems to be always 0...

Comment: switched two lines so the nextInt() will be after the product. SOLVED. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accept the user input instead as:

```
number = sc.nextInt(); // input once
while ( number != 0) {
    prod = prod * number;
    number = sc.nextInt(); // input for next iterations
}
```

With your current solution, you might need to input `0` twice to skip out of the `while`, since one of the scanned input governs the logic of iterating while the other evaluates into the product(which would eventually be 0).

Answer (score 0):

in the code you tried, you are consuming 2 times the scanner input 1 for check the condition and 1 for the multiplication value...

you can use another variable and inside the while proof whether the input is different from zero

```
int inp = -1;
while (inp != 0) {
    System.out.println("give input: ");

    number = sc.nextInt();
    inp = number;
    if (number != 0)
        prod *= number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine reading user input and checking stop condition in one line within the *while* loop in a style that is more elegant but less readable...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Product{
Scanner sc = new Scanner( System. in );
int number,prod=1;
void doProd(){
while( sc.hasNext() && 0!= (number=sc.nextInt()) ){
prod = prod * number;
}
System.out.println( "Product is "+ prod );
}
public static void main( String[]  args ) {
(new Product()).doProd();
}
}
```